# How to enable/disable a button ("resend code" button for phone verification) in relation to a countdown timer?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a button and it should appear in 30 seconds. The countdown starts from 30 seconds. When it reaches 0, the resend code button should appear/enable.

[image]

Comment: Please try to explain your problem clearly.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do it like this using `Timer` from `dart:async`..

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  int secondsRemaining = 30;
  bool enableResend = false;
  Timer timer;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (_) {
      if (secondsRemaining != 0) {
        setState(() {
          secondsRemaining--;
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          enableResend = true;
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        TextField(),
        const SizedBox(height: 10),
        FlatButton(
          child: Text('Submit'),
          color: Colors.blue,
          onPressed: () {
            //submission code here
          },
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 30),
        FlatButton(
          child: Text('Resend Code'),
          onPressed: enableResend ? _resendCode : null,
        ),
        Text(
          'after $secondsRemaining seconds',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 10),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
  
  void _resendCode() {
    //other code here
    setState((){
      secondsRemaining = 30;
      enableResend = false;
    });
  }
  
  @override
  dispose(){
    timer.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
  
}
```

Link to the code on Dartpad -
https://dartpad.dev/a59c751c4f6b4721a7af1cc27c67650b

Answer (score 0):

For someone searching for this solution for new Versions of Flutter, which has null safety.
You need to make some changes to the verified code shared by Jigar Patel above.

1. Timer? timer;
2. timer?.cancel();

Reason: adding ? will help you to bypass null safety.

Now coming to use [Resend OTP Functionality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9YtX.png)

I've arranged two containers in a Column,
first Container for Resend OTP Button and second Container to show timer like this:

```
children:[
  Container(
   width: 150,
   margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 410),
   child: InkWell(**onTap: () => enableResend ? _resendCode() : null,**
                                      child: Text(
                                        "Resend OTP",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 13,
                                            **color: enableResend
                                                ? Color(0xff3E64FF)
                                                : Colors.grey,**
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            fontFamily:'Raleway'),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ), 
const SizedBox(height: 5),
Container(
  width: 150,
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 390),
  child: InkWell(
         **child: Text(
                   '(after $secondsRemaining seconds)',
                   style: TextStyle( color: Color(0xff3E64FF), fontSize: 10),**
    ),
   ),
 ),

], )
```

so here with respect to Jigar Patel's code, I've changed:

3. `_resendCode()` instead of just using `_resendCode`, because on clicking resend button function should be called.

```
**onTap: () => enableResend ? _resendCode() : null,**
```

4. In `_resendCode()` function,
   I've called my own function named "send code on email"  - you can put your own resend Code function here.

```
    //other code here
    **SendCodeOnEmail ();**
    setState(() {
      secondsRemaining = 30;
      enableResend = false;
    });
  }
```

5. `color: enableResend? Color(0xff3E64FF): Colors.grey,`

so that [Resend OTP text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBpV9.png) 
is **disabled for 30 seconds and it's colour changes to grey, and when it is enabled it changes to blue**