# How to disable a button in flutter when a user click on it and a time is displayed instead?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `TextButton` the code below:

```
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  sendAgainVerify();
             
                },
                child: Text(
                  'OK', 
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ),
```

I want it to be disabled when the user click on it, and to be displayed for 1min (count down)
instead of OK

This button is coded for this. When the code is not sent to the SMS user, the user clicks on it to send the code again.

```
  void sendAgainVerify() async {
    var response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse(
            "https://localhost/backend/api/v1/auth/mobile/confirm/resend"),
        body: ({
          "mobile": _mobileSeller,
        }));

    final body = jsonDecode(response.body);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
          .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('${body['success']}')));
    } else {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
          .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('${body['error']}')));
    }
  }
```

Comment: **Please try These method:-** **Future Delayed:-**
https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/dart/future+delayed+flutter **Timer:-** https://blog.logrocket.com/understanding-flutter-timer-class-timer-periodic/ ***Note***: Please read carefully these are documentation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62952821/how-to-enable-disable-a-button-resend-code-button-for-phone-verification-in This might help you to achieve your needs!!
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import 'dart:async';

Timer _timer;
int _start = 60;
String _defaultText = 'OK';

void startTimer() {
  const oneSec = const Duration(seconds: 1);
  _timer = new Timer.periodic(
    const Duration(seconds: 1),
    (Timer timer) {
      if (_start == 0) {
        setState(() {
          timer.cancel();
          _defaultText = 'OK';
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          _start--;
          _defaultText = '$_start';
        });
      }
    },
  );
}

@override
void dispose() {
  _timer.cancel();
  super.dispose();
}

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body:               
      TextButton(
        onPressed: () {
          startTimer();
          sendAgainVerify();
        },
        child: Text(
          _defaultText, 
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
      ),
  );
}
```